# Show that $g \circ f$ has an inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

$g \circ f$

Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ have an inverse. Show that $g \circ f$ has an inverse.

One way I think on how to do this is by showing that it is a bijective function.

So for ease of use I've called $g \circ f = h(x)$ (don't know if im allowed to do this in algebra)

*Injective:*

Choose $x_1, x_2$ such that $h(x_1) = h(x_2)$

$x_1 = h^{-1}(h(x_1)) = h^{-1}(h(x_2)) = h^{-1} \circ h(x_2) = x_2$

*Surjective:*

For any $y ∈ Y$ we choose $x=h^{-1}(y)∈X$,

$h(x) = h(h^{-1}(y)) = h \circ h^{-1}(y) = y$

Is this correct?

Comment: your proof is circular as you are assuming it has a inverse to show that it is one one, you can rather guess a function which you think would be the inverse and then show that it is indeed a inverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more convenient way would be to make the claim that: $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g\circ f$. And we prove this claim thus:

Note that $f$ and $g$ have inverses: $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ resp, so $f\circ f^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ f = Id$ and $g\circ g^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ g = Id$. And $f^{-1} : B\rightarrow A$ and $g^{-1} : C\rightarrow B$. Then $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1} : C\rightarrow A$ is well defined as it is a composition of two maps. In particular, note the following;
$$ (g\circ f) \circ (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) = g\circ (f\circ f^{-1})\circ g^{-1} = g\circ (Id)\circ g^{-1} = g\circ g^{-1} = Id $$
The last result holds by associativity of composition of maps.

Similarly, one gets that $$ (f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}) \circ (g\circ f) = Id $$

And the claim follows.

Comment: So, from what I know, $f \circ f^{-1} = id_y$ and only $i_y \circ f=f$ but you've written $g \circ i_y = g$.

Comment: The latter is also true.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the terms you've used. $I_d$ is $i_y$ ?

Comment: It's just about the notations. $Id$ for me is the identity map, the domain depends on the context. But whichever the domain/codomain, they all satisfy virtually the same properties

Comment: Got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $(g\circ f)(x)=h(x)$. Since $f,g$ have an inverse, $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x)$ is defined. Verify that

$$h\circ(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})=\mathbf{1_C}~~~\text{and}~~~(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ h=\mathbf{1_A}$$

where $\mathbf{1_C}$ and $\mathbf{1_A}$ are the identity functions of $C$ and $A$ respectively.